# Two ListBoxes - one returning an empty value

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a UserForm in VBA with two ListBoxes. Each box gets filled during `UserForm_Initialize()`. I use a loop for this, so that only text items are added to the UserForm and empty cells are ignored:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 8
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(2 + i, 10) <> "" Then
            ListBox1.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(2 + i, 10)
        End If
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 7
        If Sheets("Data").Cells(11 + i, 10) <> "" Then
            ListBox2.AddItem Sheets("Data").Cells(11 + i, 10)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

The user can either (single-) select one entry in each ListBox or alternatively use a button to load/select the previous values from two cells in a sheet:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonLoad_Click()
    ListBox1.Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(15, 1)
    ListBox2.Value = Sheets("Input").Cells(17, 1)
End Sub
```

Another button will then write the selected ListBox values in the (same) cells that contained the previous values.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonConfirm_Click()
    Sheets("Input").Cells(15, 1) = ListBox1.Value
    Sheets("Input").Cells(17, 1) = ListBox2.Value
End Sub
```

The problem:
As long as I select the ListBox items by hand in the UserForm, everything works as intended an the third code will re-write the correct values (which are text by the way) in the cells (15, 1) and (17, 1). However, if I use the button (code 2) to fill the ListBoxes with previous values from the sheet, only one ListBox gets assigned with the correct value (output "Item XYZ"). The other one gets an empty value (output: "").

The issue vanishes when I use tab to select the ListBoxes in the UserForm. I guess this is equal to selecting the item with the mouse cursor.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Especially since one of the two ListBoxes works as intended. Anyone know the cause for this?

**Edit:** To clarify: Using the "Load" button, both values get correctly selected in the ListBoxes. But the assigned value of one ListBox ist empty (tested using `msgbox ListBox1.value` and `msgbox ListBox2.value`).
One more thing: If I add  `ListBox1.SetFocus` and `ListBox2.SetFocus` to `CommandButtonLoad` the problem gets solved. But I still don't know what caused it.

Comment: Have you tried using `ListBox1.Text` instead of `.value`?

Comment: Is the other one a numeric value? If yes use Cstr(Sheets("Input")....

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. I added 2 listboxes and 2 buttons to a userform and added your code, if I press the confirm button the selected values get wirtten into the input sheet, if I press the load button, then in both listboxes the correct values are selected. I used `A, B, C, …` as example data and it all worked like expected.

Comment: When you hit the `CommandButtonLoad`, do the correct values in the listboxes get highlighted/selected?

Comment: @horst no differece
@ EvR Nope. All cells have the same format.
@StavrosJon Nope. The value for `Sheets("Input").Cells(15, 1)` is correct ("Item XYZ"), but the value for `ListBox1.Value` ist wrong ("").

Comment: To clarify: Using the "Load" button, both values get correctly selected in the ListBoxes. But the assigned value of one ListBox ist empty (tested using `msgbox ListBox1.value` and `msgbox ListBox2.value`).

Comment: One more thing: If I add  `ListBox1.SetFocus` and `ListBox2.SetFocus` to `CommandButtonLoad` the problem gets solved. But I still don't know what caused it.

Comment: @blowcake where did you add the `msgbox`? In which part of the code does the value get "lost". Is it the `Load` part, is it the `confirm` part, is it both?

Comment: @StavrosJon I added the msgbox at the end of the `Load` part. But you can also see the wrong value by simply going through the code line by line with F8.

Comment: @blowcake Have you maybe messed around with their properties? Are you sure both of the listboxes are `Enabled` and not `Locked`? This behavior would hint me towards that direction...

Comment: @blowcake in fact, what you describe is exactly what happens if the `listbox` is not `Enabled`. You can set these properties by code but it's even easier to do it through the object's properties browser.

Comment: @StavrosJon I made sure both `ListBoxes` have the same properties (besides their position). Both are `enabled`.

Comment: I can reproduce this behaviour when the Userform is opened Modeless, do you open it Modeless?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonConfirm_Click()

    Sheets("Data").Cells(15, 1) = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)
    Sheets("Data").Cells(17, 1) = ListBox2.List(ListBox2.ListIndex)

End Sub
```